# Espresso intent error: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm reviewn some espresso test of one of the google's tutorials to can learn some espresso testing. I'm trying to run a test but is failing and not sure where is the problem. I'm doing some research here to can find the error and run correctly the test, but I don't know where coulb be the problem.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class PlantDetailFragmentTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val activityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(GardenActivity::class.java)

    @Before
    fun jumpToPlantDetailFragment() {
        activityTestRule.activity.apply {
            runOnUiThread {
                val bundle = Bundle().apply { putString("plantId", testPlant.plantId) }
                findNavController(R.id.garden_nav_fragment).navigate(R.id.plant_detail_fragment, bundle)
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testShareTextIntent() {
        val shareText = activityTestRule.activity.getString(R.string.share_text_plant, testPlant.name)

        Intents.init()
        onView(withId(R.id.action_share)).perform(click())
        intended(
            chooser(
                allOf(
                    hasAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND),
                    hasType("text/plain"),
                    hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText)
                )
            )
        )
        Intents.release()

        // dismiss the Share Dialog
        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
            .uiAutomation
            .performGlobalAction(AccessibilityService.GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK)
    }
}

fun chooser(matcher: Matcher<Intent>): Matcher<Intent> = allOf(
    hasAction(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER),
    hasExtra(`is`(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT), matcher)
)
```

ERROR:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

IntentMatcher: (has action: is "android.intent.action.CHOOSER" and has extras: has bundle with: key: is "android.intent.extra.INTENT" value: (has action: is "android.intent.action.SEND" and has type: is "text/plain" and has extras: has bundle with: key: is "android.intent.extra.TEXT" value: is "Check out the Apple plant in the Android Sunflower app"))

Matched intents:[]

Recorded intents:
-Intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER flg=0x8080000 (has extras) } handling packages:[[android]], extras:[Bundle[{android.intent.extra.INTENT=Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain flg=0x80001 (has clip) (has extras) }}]])
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
at androidx.test.espresso.intent.VerificationModes$Times.verify(VerificationModes.java:80)
at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntended(Intents.java:346)
at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents$3.run(Intents.java:204)
at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents$PropogatingRunnable.run(Intents.java:224)
at android.app.Instrumentation$SyncRunnable.run(Instrumentation.java:1885)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5931)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:987)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
```